# SSH Forwarding with Squid

Tags: ssh, vpn, proxy, forwarding, squid

I would like to ssh into a box that isn't front facing (box a).  I have an offsite box (box b) that I have OpenVPN running on and box a is connected to that VPN so box b can interface with box a.  Now, what I want to set up is that if I run `ssh -p 2001 user@(box b)`, box b forwards that tunnel to box a and I can then ssh into it.

I am thinking that I need something like Squid to be running on box b so when ssh traffic comes in through port 2001, it will forward that tunnel to box a and return box a's shell.

Basically, I want a way of sshing into box a through box b without having to connect to be first, and then open an ssh tunnel to box a.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!